# VBA Excel - The Hangman

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to develop a code for the hangman using the template in this picture. http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/files/exercise-images/e1759/i3892.gif

I think I have managed to do that; however, one problem that I have is that the when the subroutine is working and the user calls for a wrong letter, the shape does not automatically color to black. It is just when the game finishes that the user can see the picture colored, whether he/she wins or loses.

Do you know any way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
Sub nuevo_juego()
'Erasing the word
Set palabra = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Game").[b2]

i = 0
While Not IsEmpty(palabra.Offset(0, i))
   i = i + 1
Wend

palabra.Resize(2, i + 1).Clear


'Hide Figure
For Each a In Worksheets("Game").Shapes
    a.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Next a


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'                    Game                      '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'User 1 introduces a word
word = InputBox("User 1: Enter a word")
n_word = Len(word)

Set palabra = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Game").[b2]

For x = 1 To n_word
    palabra.Offset(0, x - 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    palabra.Offset(0, x - 1) = Mid(word, x, 1)
Next x

'Count the number of shapes (tries) the person has
n_shapes = Worksheets("Game").Shapes.Count

Set inicio = palabra.Offset(1, 0)

s = 0

Do

'Count the number of words the user has guessed
n_guess = WorksheetFunction.CountA(inicio.Resize(1, n_word))

'If the number of letters guessed is equal to the length of the word and the last shape is still white, you win
If n_guess = n_word And Worksheets("Game").Shapes(n_shapes).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) 
Then
    MsgBox ("Ganaste!!")
    mensaje = 1

'If the number of letters guessed is less than the length of the word and the last shape is black, you win
ElseIf n_guess < n_word And Worksheets("Game").Shapes(n_shapes).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
    MsgBox ("Perdiste!!")
    mensaje = 1

'Otherwise, we keep playing
Else
    'User 2 guesses a letter
    letra = InputBox("User 2: Guess a letter", 
"Hangman")

'Ask letter by letter of the word chosen by user 1 if it is equal to the guessed letter. If it is, then we put the letter in the cell below. We count if there is any math in cont.
cont = 0
For j = 0 To n_word - 1
    If palabra.Offset(0, j).Value = letra Then
        cont = cont + 1
        inicio.Offset(0, j) = palabra.Offset(0, j)
    End If
Next j

'If there was not a match, then a shape is colored (HERE IS MY PROBLEM). If not, keep playing.
    If cont = 0 Then
        s = s + 1
        MsgBox ("There was not a match, please try again. You have " & 9 - s & " tries left")
        Worksheets("Game").Shapes(s).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox ("You guessed a letter!")
    End If

End If

Loop Until mensaje = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: add DoEvents before your Loop Until mensaje = 1 as it sounds like it is a screen updating issue, unless this is not all the code and you turn screen updating on/off somewhere.

Comment: Yes, this is all the code. It worked with screenupdating option, thanks!